# Can we see live preview in adobe xd using Windows 10?

Tags: mobile, windows, adobe-xd, live-trace

Hi I am trying to see the live update in the adobe xd app but I am not able to do so, is it some kind of update that xd has come with?

I am using a Windows 10 Laptop and Tried connecting my USB cable with my mobile device.
But When I am clicking on preview it is showing that I need to see the designs using the mobile app (Which is not showing me live working changes)

Screenshot
[image]

Do I need a MAC to have this feature?

Comment: Docs are pretty unclear about it too. If you have to save it as a cloud document, it doesn't sound very live previewy, but who knows. Maybe check the "How can I set up Android devices to preview Adobe XD projects?" in https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/adobe-xd-mobile-faq.html#react-spectrum-47 — I did find this uservoice post https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/34933828-live-xd-preview-on-android and this one  https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/42205351-disable-live-preview-for-android-app

Comment: I found this ["If your device is running Adobe XD on Windows 10, real-time preview through USB is not supported on Android."](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/preview-mobile.html#live-preview) but if they specify it doesn't work in Windows 10... I would kinda assume it works in some other version, but they are not saying it works in Windows 11 either. They also specifically say "through usb"... so does it work over wifi? like being a bit broader would've actually made it clearer if they had said "Android real time preview doesn't work on Windows".

Comment: Reading this post https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd-discussions/live-preview-mobile-still-not-working/td-p/10567192 I get the feeling it might work in some very specific setup but it's experimental enough that they aren't allowed to say it works. Someone brought it up on this post too that it's odd how they never seem to admit it doesn't work from windows to android. Though some of the comments in that post are a bit old.

Comment: See https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/preview-mobile.html - it says "If your device is running Adobe XD on Windows 10, real-time preview through USB is not supported on Android." - I think that's pretty clear. It doesn't work. Save as a cloud document instead, then you can open it in the XD app on Android.  It's not "live" though.  But you could just hit Ctrl+S to save on the desktop XD, and reload the document in the Android XD app.  I've no idea if the USB cable live preview works on a Mac with an Android device as I can't test it since I'm on Windows.  Perhaps a Mac user can tell you.

Comment: Dear @Joonas Thank you for all your efforts but after all the articles and links, I believe this is not anymore available for Android devices, because I have tested using an Apple I phone and it was working :( but thanks again :)

Comment: Dear @BillyKerr I understand your point, and it is true, but I used this function 2 years back using a Windows + Android phone. But sad that it's not for android anymore. But thanks again :)

Comment: @SumitYadav - I think did work initially, but then it broke, and Adobe hasn't fixed it - so now they just say it is "unsupported".

Answer (score -1):

Just to make it clear this is issue is within Windows and USB protcolls. Windows will not change things. Adobe have asked and tried to make them solve this issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113860)